# How to use one event in another

Tags: c#

I need to use one event in another event. I'm beginner and I don't know how to do it. I want to use the first event in the second event.

//First event

```
private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        {
            sw.Write(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

//second event

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult rezult = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca doriti sa iesiti din program !?",
        "Aplication closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
    if (rezult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //I want to use first event in this if,please help me;
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else if (rezult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Extract the functionality to a separate function and call it in both event handlers.

Comment: i explain it not very well,i wanted not to use the same code in two events,i wanted when i close my app to save it.But i have one event with this code(save),and i believed that i can to call him in my second event...

Answer (score 7):

Move that code to a separate function, then call that function in both event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `this.saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null)` in your `Form1_FormClosing` method (since the parameters aren't actually used). However, I'd strongly recommend refactoring the save logic into a separate method, and invoking it where appropriate, like this:

```
private void Save() 
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt|All files(*.*)|";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        {
            sw.Write(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}

private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.Save();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    DialogResult rezult = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca doriti sa iesiti din program !?",
        "Aplication closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
    if (rezult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.Save();
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else if (rezult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For today, just call first one as a function like this

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult rezult = MessageBox.Show("Sunteti sigur ca doriti sa iesiti din program !?",
        "Aplication closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
    if (rezult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // call other event handler as a function, for it is one
        saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null);

        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else if (rezult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

And tomorrow, read a blog/book/article about Document/View, Model/View/Controller, Model/View/ViewModel.